# How NopCommerce loads admin area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef, nopcommerce

The question is so simple. How NopCommerce web project (`Nop.Web`) loads the `Admin` area while it's separately in another `DLL` placed in root projects `bin` dir?

I have worked around [`AutoFac`](https://autofac.org/) but seems it's not related to this.

Comment: See, there `Nop.Web` has `Administration` folder and `Nop.Admin` output path is `Nop.Web` > `bin`

Comment: Yes @Div, it's published in `bin` folder, but how the `Nop.Web.dll` find and loads that?

Comment: My project is based on NopCommerce, so the question is directly related to Nop's infrastructure

Comment: *My project is based on NopCommerce* nopCommerce based on ASP.NET, *so the question is directly related to Nop's infrastructure* Nope,  directly related to [Bin folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295391.aspx)

Comment: Refer upper link, there is a statement *You can **store compiled assemblies in the Bin folder**, and other code anywhere in the web application (such as code for pages) **automatically references it***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Global.asax.cs from Nop.Web and then see Application_Start in method and you can see a line there

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

By this line it registers all area of your domain.

**The RegisterAllAreas method finds all types in the application domain that derive from AreaRegistration and calls each of their RegisterArea methods.**

For more info check this [link.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.arearegistration.registerallareas(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: thanks @Anik, this is what i was looking for. but it seems the Nop developers has changed some rules in `ThemeableRazorViewEngine.cs`, because `~/admin` loads the view from `Administration/Views` instead of `~/areas/Admin/Views`

Comment: It will be better ThemeableVirtualPathProviderViewEngine.cs so that you can understand it better. You can talk with Mr.Andrei in nopcommerce forum he will surely help you to understand nopcommerce structure more clearly.

Comment: actually can you see this method 
protected virtual string GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, string[] locations, string[] areaLocations, string locationsPropertyName, string name, string controllerName, string theme, string cacheKeyPrefix, bool useCache, out string[] searchedLocations)